# Making a Grafana timeseries graph for each document in my mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb, time-series, grafana

I have a mongodb collection with 2 arrays per document. “FRAME” and “NOSE_Y”. They’re the same length as eachother, and the FRAME array simply ascends from 0 (eg. [0, 1, 2, 3, 4…]). What I am trying to do is use the FRAME as the time value x axis and NOSE_Y as the y axis value.

However, grafana isn’t able to recognize my data as valid time series format. I suspect it’s because the datapoints contain “map” before each array for some reason, but I think it could also be because my whole approach to this is wrong? What I mean by that is this is what the table view shows:

[image: Table view]

Any help would be much appreciated. This is the query I’m using:

```
human_pos.POS.aggregate([
    {"$match": {"FRAME": {"$exists": true}}},
    {"$project": {
        "data": {
            "$zip": {
                "inputs": ["$FRAME", "$NOSE_Y"]
            }
        }
    }},
    {"$unwind": "$data"},
    {"$project": {
        "time": {"$multiply": [{"$arrayElemAt": ["$data", 0]}, 1000]},
        "value": {"$arrayElemAt": ["$data", 1]},
        "_id": 0,
        "doc_id": "$_id"
    }},
    {"$sort": {"time": 1}},
    {"$group": {
        "_id": "$doc_id",
        "datapoints": {"$push": {"value": "$value", "time": "$time"}}
    }}
])
```

Comment: I don't know about mongo part, but grafana is not really designed for this. Could your frame data be in any reasonable way converted into timestamps?

Comment: Hmm, could you elaborate on what you mean by timestamps? Can't the frame data simply be converted to seconds (like in the multiply by 1000 part)?

Comment: Something like that. But maybe also add some initial offset. Like 4 -> 4*60 + 1679552506, where 1679552506 is some sort of global start timestamp.